# Uniformly Distributed points on a plane are getting clustered in java, why?

Tags: java, random

I want to generate uniformly distributed circles/points/nodes on a *100 plane. For that I am using the Random() method in java. Specifically I am doing it in in the following manner:

```
Random r1=new Random();
  for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
  x=100*r1.nextDouble();
  y=100*r1.nextDouble();
}
```

But the problem is that as I run the code over and over again, the nodes are not uniformly spaced on the plane, i.e., there are clusters of concentrations and some chunks of un-occupied space.

Any ideas, recommendations would be highly appreciated.
The image belows shows a typical output with the clusters and the white spaces. The number of the circles are just the IDs of the circles.
[image]

Comment: It's a common misconception that random numbers are unclustered. They most definitely do form clusters if there aren't enough of them. If you want uniformity then code up a uniform generator (divide up the plane evenly and put points on accordingly).

Comment: Thank you for your response, can you clarify more please. I didn't get the part where u said to divide the plane evenly and put the nodes accordingly.

Comment: @Anderson You should have a look at the [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Comment: I am looking to it right now. It helps as well Thx.

Comment: The question can't be answered without knowing what you intend to use the points for. Maybe you really do need them smoothly distributed for visual effect, in which case you don't want them random. But maybe you really do need them random and your discomfort with clumps and voids is just a misunderstanding you need to get over. So what's your actual application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want your random distribution to look more "even", that is you want to cover the space more evenly, you cannot use a completely uniform distribution, since it will contain "gaps", as @Adam pointed out.

You can use instead something called [Low-discrepancy sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence): [Halton sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halton_sequence) for instance, or [Sobol sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobol_sequence). As you can see in the Wikipedia example pictures, they avoid clusters and gaps you will have with uniform distributions.

Comment: Thank you very much, I quickly saw the pics in wikipedia and it is exactly what I am looking for random but with no gaps. Just a quick question so are these "Low-discrepancy sequences" are considered some implementation of the uniform distribution? because they look uniformly distributed to me. Thank you again.

Comment: They are uniform. It's easy to see for the Halton sequence, it's just subdividing the range evenly on x and evenly on y, just a different "evenly".

Comment: @Flavio do you know what the best way to add jitter would be? Obviously you can randomly perturb the coordinates, but how would that affect uniformity?

Comment: Those two images show exactly what I want to aheive and what I want to avoid

Comment: To add jitter you might move each point with a normal distribution: `(x,y)=(x+rnd.nextGaussian() * S, y+rnd.nextGaussian()*S)` where S controls how much movement you want to allow. However choose a small S or you will defeat your main purpose of avoiding clusters and gaps.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean a 100x100 unit plane, with 100 points.

A 10x10 grid overlaid over your plane, with 1 point per grid box means 100 evenly distributed points.

Place points in the center for exact uniformity that's pretty:

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    x = 5 + 10*(i/10);
    y = 5 + i % 10;
}
```

Or for a little bit of jitter, randomize the location within each grid box:

```
Random r1=new Random();
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    x = 10*r1.nextDouble() + 10*(i/10);
    y = 10*r1.nextDouble() + i % 10;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that. However i am looking for something that is not a grid. I mean by looking to the circles in the attached figure, some portions are so heavily loaded while others are not some I am looking for a way to move from the extreme setting which I have now to some what more uniform distribution (but not a grid). Is there any thing that I can with the random number generator, i.e., to use a 2nd R.N.G for the Y-coordinates or something like that? Thx

Comment: The second approach can be adjusted by using a larger/smaller grid to control your uniformity. If you use a 5x5 grid with 4 random points per box then you have more randomness, less uniformity, but not as much as in your solution. In fact your solution is what happens with a 1x1 grid.